# Set speaker phone on even handset is attached in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, speaker

Generally it happens that when we attach hand set to phone, the speaker automatically goes to off  mode.
Is it possible to set speaker on and also same time handset also attached?

If not possible then please explain the reason.

Thank You.